# getting error in ionic serve in Terminal after updating nodejs

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ionic-framework, npm

I am using ubuntu 15.10

ionic  version 1.7.15.

I was trying to update my nodejs to laters version 6 and npm and after that when i run **ionic server** command i am getting error shown in [image: img]

the command i used to update

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

how to to downgrade my nodejs

when i use **whereis node** command

> node: /usr/local/bin/node /opt/node/bin/node

when i use **whereis nodejs** command

> nodejs:

when i use **whereis npm** command

> npm: /usr/local/bin/npm /opt/node/bin/npm

I think i have to use lower version of node but i dont know how to do is i have tried my cmd but no use

Comment: `ENOSPC` suggests that your filesystem might be full.

Comment: @robertklep what is the solution now what i should do now

Comment: how do i make one and where should i make a directory

Comment: i think if i use lower node version i will be able to work with ionic because after upgarding node to version6 i'm facing this error

Comment: @robertklep https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6340 look here and i tried but no use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by mention the version of node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n v4.2.3 //By mentioning the version while i install i solved this error on serve
```

i switched my node version from v6 to v4 so then i got no error